# CTE Recursion without clear root node

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like the following:

```
ID  ParentID    ChildID
1   465         547
2   547         653
3   653         667
4   902         1005
5   1005        1009
6   1059        1080
```

Note: ParentID and ChildID refer to another table of people.

My goal is to identify the root parent and count the number of children. For example the expected query output would be:

```
ParentID    NumChildren
465         3
902         2
1059        1
```

I have seen some examples using recursion in CTE when there is a clear identifier of a parent, such as an entry with parentid = null. But my data is not structured in that manner so I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select script in CTE, to get Only Root Parent ID list which are not exists in Child ID

Second select script after UNION ALL in CTE, to get Heirarchy data, use UNION ALL and JOIN with same CTE as a parent Child ID with Parent ID column of main table i.e. #tblA

You need to use aggregate function COUNT() to get child count against Parent ID
You need to use GROUP BY clause to use aggregate function COUNT()

Please check below script for your expected result.

```
SELECT
    A.*
    INTO #tblA
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 ID,465 ParentID,547 ChildID UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,547,653 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,653,667 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,902,1005 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,1005,1009 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,1059,1080
) A

;WITH CTE_REC
AS
(
    --Get Only Root Parent ID list which are not exists in Child ID
    SELECT
        A.ParentID,A.ChildID
    FROM #tblA A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM #tblA c
        WHERE c.ChildID = A.ParentID
    )
    --to get Heirarchy data, use UNION ALL and JOIN with same CTE as a parent Child ID with Parent ID column of main table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CR.ParentID,ta.ChildID
    FROM CTE_REC CR
    INNER JOIN #tblA ta ON ta.ParentID = CR.ChildID
)
SELECT
    c.ParentID,
    COUNT(c.ChildID) AS NumChildren --Use aggregate function count() to get child count against parent id
FROM CTE_REC c
GROUP BY c.ParentID; -- Use Group By Clause to use aggregate function count()

DROP TABLE #tblA;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a check that a parent is never a child.

```
with cte as (
select  ParentID, ChildID  
  from TABLE  
where parentid not in (select childid from TABLE ) -- the parent is never a child

  union all

  select  parent.ParentID, child.ChildID
  from TABLE child
  inner join cte parent
  on child.parentid =parent.ChildID
)
select ParentID,count(*) as NumChildren
from cte
group by ParentID
```